# как восстановить состояние после git rebase

Tags: git

**Предиcтория фейла:**

В *origin master* было 10 нормальных коммитов. Понадобилось 3 коммита извлечь из истории, а потом перенести в отдельный баранч

**Вот мои действия**

```
git checkout master
git branch test
git rebase -i HEAD~10 //удалил 3,9 и 10 коммит (условно hash: aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc)
git push -f origin master
git checkout test
git rebase -i HEAD~10 //удалил 4,5,6,7,8 тоесть промежуточные
```

В это время мастер пошел вперед. Решив что пора вылить ветку *test* в *origin*, но что бы потом сливать ветку было проще решил подлить в нее мастер но ребейсом

```
git checkout test
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Расчитывал что мои три коммита просто перетянуться вверх истории, так как предок-коммит был. Но после кучу странных конфликтов в истории отсуствует один коммит (**aaaa**)

**Два вопроса**

1. В чем я ошибся и почему все так сломалось?
2. Что делать, как востановить утерянный коммит?

Comment: как пофиксить я уже понял, все просто git reflog, находим состояние проекта до пула (например 3 шага назад) и делаем git reset --hard HEAD@{3}. Можно также и брачь временный создать что бы поразбераться. Но так и незнаю как правильно подлить без мерджа новые комиты в ветку

Comment: `git cherry-pick` не?

Comment: git cherry-pick ну эта команда укороченная версия git rebase только для одного коммита у меня конечно всего три комита, но на практике так легко не бывает

Comment: вы в мастер форсом пушнули ?

Comment: да, я форсом в мастер пушнул

Comment: Чтобы лучше понять гит: http://habrahabr.ru/post/268951/

Comment: так я книгу по гиту прочитал и понял как работает гит, но на нюансах запутаться легко. Могу логически расписать что я сделал

    git pull -- rebase origin master это: 
    git fetch origin master; 
    git rebase HEAD origin/master; 

при ребейсе находиться кореневой коммит между ветками и начинаеться перетаскивание трех моих комитов через каждый зашедший из мастера
Но гдето я неправ, и поэтому потерялся коммит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ для второго пункта: все просто `git reflog`, находим состояние проекта до пула (например 3 шага назад) и делаем `git reset --hard HEAD@{3}`. Можно так же и бранч временный создать, чтобы поразбираться.

Comment: а для первого пункта?

Comment: @4per ответ для первого пункта: из за того что мастер ушел вперед и в этих комитах были удалены файлы в которые вносит изменение коммит 3 (ааааааа) и поэтому при ребейсе он наверно проигнорировался.